# Changing border color when 2 checkboxes are selected (and also disabling the rest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Can't get my head around this, trying to not only disable the rest of the checkboxes after two are selected, but also to turn the border around the "checkbox_group" from black to red

The javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cbox").on("click", function(){
var numberOfChecked = $('input.cbox:checkbox:checked').length;
if (numberOfChecked === 3){
$(this).prop('checked', false);
$("#checkbox_group").css({"border-color":"red"});
} else {
$("#checkbox_group").css({"border-color":"black"});
}
//console.log(numberOfChecked); // debugging
});
});
```

The styling for the div in question is:

```
#checkbox_group{
    border: solid black 1px;               
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="checkbox_group">
    <label>Sports</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="Sports" value="Sports" ><br>
    <label>News</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="News" value="News" ><br>
    <label>Entertainment</label
    ><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="Entertainment" value="Entertainment" ><br>
    <label>Music</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="Music" value="Music" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the if statement to equal `2` instead of `3`. Then you need to check through the checkboxs and find which ones aren't checked already.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".cbox").on("click", function(){
var numberOfChecked = $('input.cbox:checkbox:checked').length;
if (numberOfChecked === 2){
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
  $(".cbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked') != true){ 
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
  });
  $("#checkbox_group").css({"border-color":"red"});
} else {
  $("#checkbox_group").css({"border-color":"black"});
  $(".cbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('disabled') == "disabled"){ 
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
}
});
});
```

```css
#checkbox_group{
    border: solid black 1px;               
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox_group">
    <label>Sports</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="Sports" value="Sports" ><br>
    <label>News</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="News" value="News" ><br>
    <label>Entertainment</label
    ><input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="Entertainment" value="Entertainment" ><br>
    <label>Music</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cbox" name="Music" value="Music" >
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, works to a point, when I un-select of the checkboxes, it then keeps all the checkboxes still disabled